# Why does tmux show `binfmt-bypass` as the window name in sessions when nvim is open?

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and I have tmux open. The window names in tmux usually display the name of the running program in the active pane.

Mostly this works as expected -- eg `bash` and `python` show up as window names when expected. But in any window with nvim running, the window name is `binfmt-bypass`, which I have never seen before.

I think this is relatively new behavior, but I can't connect it to any specific recent changes. This isn't a huge problem but just confusing and would like to understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because of the appimage initially uses it and then it gets renamed to it. I haven't figured out more than that, removing the appimage and using the one installed by the package manager fixed it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).